# Adding functions with arguments to javascript array and then executing them

Tags: javascript

I have a function as below:

```
function callme(x,y) {
  return function() {
    console.log("value of x = " + x);
    console.log("value of y = " + y); 
  }
}
```

I would like to add the above function to an array and then execute them

```
var steps = [];
steps.push(callme(1,2));
steps.push(callme(2,3));

steps[0];  // should execute first function
steps[1];  // should execute second function
```

For some reason the parameters I am passing to the function are not getting stored.

Anyone anyclues as to what I might be doing wrong ?

Comment: `steps[0]` _shouldn't_ execute a function. Add parenthesis to the end.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way but: I'm more confused of how many different ways there are to do this in Javascript, than why someone would want to do this in the first place :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**EDITED**. Bad answer on my part as I somehow overlooked the fact that callme() indeed returns a function.

Comment: Has the OP edited the question? The current question's `callme()` function does not return `undefined`.

Comment: You solution did help Oscar.. I also need to execute a callback on every .. how do i incorporate that ?

Comment: Does the fact that this answer was accepted mean that Stack Overflow is broken? :-|

Comment: @JamesHans, though the last part of my answer (about calling the funcitons in the array) was correct. I find it unfair for the other users who answered more concisely that I gain the reputation points for the best answer. Can't you change it, especially now I edited my post.

Comment: @OscarPaz - [This answer on queues](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15581959/451969) might help.

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually *calling* the methods. Calling methods involves using the bracket syntax as shown below:

```
steps[0]();  // should execute first function
steps[1]();  // should execute second function
```

***Edit***

Jared has kindly worked up a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vv6wb/).

***Second Edit***

In your comments you've asked for added callback functionality. Even though this should probably be a separate question, I'll throw a bone for now:

```
function callme(x, y, callback) {
  return function() {
    console.log("value of x = " + x);
    console.log("value of y = " + y);
    callback();
  }
}
```

I'm assuming you'll want to call the functions programmatically in order (from your array), so you'll probably need something like this:

```
var steps = [];

steps.push(callme(1, 2, next));
steps.push(callme(2, 3, next));

var i = -1;

function next(){

  i++

  if(i < steps.length){

    steps[i]();

  }
}

next();
```

It should be noted though that this sort of sequential calling of methods can be a slippery slope. Mainly because your callback method is being called before the last callback has finished executing, leading to possible stack overflow errors.

You're better off looking into design patterns: middleware and promises is a good place to start.

Comment: I don't know if the OP modified the question, but the answers that say the array parts would be `undefined` are not correct for the *current* version of the question. All that's needed is the above (`()` on the end). Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vv6wb/

Comment: Thanks shennan.. i do know about this.. the bigger picture is that I nee deach function to execute a callback function.. any idea how I can achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

you should call like this

```
steps[0]();
steps[1]();
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute each function, you need to invoke it.

So this line `steps[0]` should actually look like this `steps[0]()`